# V-edit-dialog close directly when start typing

Tags: vuetify.js

this is a pen :  https://codepen.io/wbuc/pen/eYNyXGa

I’m using the v-edit-dialog in the data table to edit a cell inline but when I start typing in the dialog that opens up, it closes directly after the first key press. What am I missing here?

thank you for help!

```
<v-data-table
          v-model="selected"
          :headers="headers"
          :items="accounts"
          :single-select="singleSelect"
          item-key="email"
          show-select
          class="elevation-3"
     >
          <template v-slot:item.email="props">
               <v-edit-dialog
                    :return-value.sync="props.item.email"
                    @save="save"
                    @cancel="cancel"
                    @open="open"
                    @close="close"
               >
                    {{ props.item.email }}
                    <template v-slot:input>
                         <v-text-field v-model="props.item.email" label="Edit" single-line counter></v-text-field>
                    </template>
               </v-edit-dialog>
          </template>
     </v-data-table>
```

Answer (score 3):

i sloved this problem by myself

```
<v-data-table
          .....
          item-key="email"      <!--Delete this or item-key="id"-->
```

we can't set a key ,and use it on the v-text-field